# angular 2/4 dropdown error

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I am trying to develop two drop downs in my Angular application. The 1st one is `shop list` and the other one is `godown list`. When I select a shop it will auto select the first one in both cases. Here I want two drop down boxes.

If I rename the function `FetchPopulateOutlets` to `ngOnInit` it works, but if there are other `ngOnInit` functions i get an error about duplicated methods.

```
 FetchPopulateOutlets() {  
  this._enqService.FetchPopulateOutlets().subscribe(outletsData => this.outletDetails = outletsData,
        error => {
            console.error(error);
            this.statusMessage = "Problem with the service.Please try again after sometime";
        });
}

onSelect(shopid: number) {       
    this._loginService.selectedshopid = shopid;      
}

FetchGodown() {
    this._enqService.FetchGodownPopulateOutlets().subscribe(GodownsData => this.GodownDetails = GodownsData,
        error => {
            console.error(error);
            this.statusMessage = "Problem with the service.Please try again after sometime";
        });
}
onSelects(godownid: number) {
    this._loginService.selectedgodownid = godownid;

}
```

MY Html is

```
<span>          
    <select class="formcontrol" name="outletDetail" (click)="FetchPopulateOutlets()" (change)="onSelect($event.target.value)">
        <option value="0" disabled>Select a Shop</option>
        <option *ngFor="let outletDetail of outletDetails" value={{outletDetail.ShopID}}>{{outletDetail.ShopName}}</option>
     </select>
</span>


<span>
    <select class="formcontrol" name="godowndata"(click)="FetchGodown()"(change)="onSelects($event.target.value)">
        <option value="0" disabled>Select a Godown</option>
        <option *ngFor="let godowndata of GodownDetails" value={{godowndata.GodownId}}>{{godowndata.GodownName}}</option>
    </select>
</span>
```

Comment: What is the error that you get? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @Cecilya here i change function FetchPopulateOutlets to ngOnInit i got the answer  but in case other ngOnInit functions i got duplicated error) here i have alredy use another function ngoninit

Comment: This is your second question. What happened to previous one?

Comment: @Antoniossss the old questions have some mistakes so i change.

Comment: To be clear, what isn't working is that you don't have the values from the backend when you click on your dropdown, except when you fetch it in the `ngOnInit` function, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please check this answer**

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this._enqService.FetchPopulateOutlets().subscribe(outletsData => this.outletDetails = outletsData,
        error => {
            console.error(error);
            this.statusMessage = "Problem with the service.Please try again after sometime";
        });

    {
        this._enqService.FetchGodownPopulateOutlets().subscribe(GodownsData => this.GodownDetails = GodownsData,
            error => {
                console.error(error);
                this.statusMessage = "Problem with the service.Please try again after sometime";
            });
```

**And change html to**

```
 <select class="formcontrol" name="outletDetail"(change)="onSelect($event.target.value)">
                    <option value="0" disabled>Select a Shop</option>
                    <option *ngFor="let outletDetail of outletDetails" value={{outletDetail.ShopID}}>{{outletDetail.ShopName}}</option>
                </select>
        </span>
    <span>
        <select class="formcontrol" name="godowndata"(change)="onSelect($event.target.value)">
            <option value="0" disabled>Select a Godown</option>
            <option *ngFor="let godowndata of GodownDetails" value={{godowndata.GodownId}}>{{godowndata.GodownName}}</option>
        </select>
    </span>
```